# cURL_init() stops the program from running

Tags: php

I have added the `.php` files on my server to send the notifications using FCM, but the code stops running when I create the actual message. I have a constructor for `push` and when I call it in `sendSinglePush`, it does not do anything.

The rest is working properly. I get the parameters ok, and the `devicetoken`. I just need to create that `push` and it should work. I've used the same `sendSinglePush.php` for testing on localhost, and it works. When I add it on server it just stops.

EDIT: As per @ADyson, who helped me understand abit about logging my errors, I started to log every variable from the start to the point where it crashes. The `$push` it's alright, the problem it's on `Firebase.php`:

```
 <?php 

class Firebase {

    public function send($registration_ids, $message) {
        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => array($registration_ids),
            'data' => $message,
        );
        //print_r($fields);
        return $this->sendPushNotification($fields);
    }

    /*
    * This function will make the actuall curl request to firebase server
    * and then the message is sent 
    */
    private function sendPushNotification($fields) {

        //importing the constant files
        require_once 'Config.php';

        //firebase server url to send the curl request
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

        //building headers for the request
        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . FIREBASE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        //Initializing curl to open a connection
        $ch = curl_init();
        print_r(curl_error($ch));
        //Setting the curl url
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        //setting the method as post
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

        //adding headers 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        //disabling ssl support
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        //adding the fields in json format 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        //finally executing the curl request 
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        print_r($result);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        print_r(curl_error($ch));
        }

        //Now close the connection
        curl_close($ch);
        //and return the result 
        return $result;

    }
}
```

And the methods are called from `sendSinglePush.php`, where all the variables are sent correctly:

```
    $mPushNotification = $push->getPush(); 
    //print_r($mPushNotification);
    //getting the token from database object 
    $devicetoken = $db->getTokenByEmail($_POST['email']);
    //print_r($devicetoken);
    //creating firebase class object 
    $firebase = new Firebase(); 

    //sending push notification and displaying result 
    $firebase->send($devicetoken, $mPushNotification);
```

I have added different `print_r()` to check the output using `POSTMAN` and, from that code, the `$headers` are fine, after the `$ch = curl_init();` nothing else shows up. I tried to add `print_r(curl_error($ch));` but it does not show enything. Also, I tried with `print_r(1);` under the `$ch = curl_init();`to see if the code keeps running, but on `postman` there was no answer, only a blank screen and `500 Internal Server Error`.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Actually no error displayed in `postman`. i have tried to add  `$response['push']= $mPushNotification;` as it should deliver an `array` but nothing shows up

Comment: what do you mean "the code stops", exactly? You mean it halts and throws an exception? If so, what is the error? (P.S. I'm assuming you've got PHP set to either display or log errors and warnings? If not, then please switch on logging of errors and warnings so that you get useful debugging info available to you.)

Comment: BTW there is some strange logic here: `if(isset($_POST['image'])){` means that if there is no image set in POST, then the $push object will not be created. Yet just below that, after the end of the `if` block, you write `$push->getPush();`, which assumes that `$push` always exists. If push must be created only when the image exists, then any code which uses $push must also be within the same `if` statement. Otherwise you are liable to get errors/warnings about undefined objects.

Comment: @ADyson I actually used the android studio debugger, to see the server's response(considering that the call to that function takes place where i also get a servers response to my app)   and the servers response its empty. It just stops after the call. The `isset` does not have a `else` because i delete it, as the server always send the image too. Just forgot to add that in the original `if`

Comment: " the servers response its empty"... and " It just stops" are not necessarily the same thing. Anyway just looking at the response is clearly not enough in this case, it isn't giving you sufficient clues. You need to add some logging / debugging in the PHP (not just error logging, necessarily, but also your own logging, to trace the flow of control and the values of variables, so that you can see exactly where / how the program goes wrong). I can't run your code, so you need to implement and test that logging yourself.

Comment: @ADyson I just implemented `echo` to see the variables, and they are alright until the construction of `$push`. I am pretty new to `php` so I do not know exactly how to implement other form of logging

Comment: " they are alright until the construction of $push"...and after that, what happens to them? You can read https://stackify.com/php-error-log-basics/ to learn how to configure logging of errors and warnings automatically.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the link! I will check it out and after that will come back with more info.